# PHP add up all values from foreach()

Tags: php, function, foreach, shopping-cart

I am making a shopping cart system, and my session is being displayed with a foreach() function. Inside this function, i have a variable called $item_price. I would like all the $item_price's to be added up so that I end up with the grand total.

How could this be done? I have no clue to how this problem should be solved :/

This is my foreach() code:

```
foreach($session_cart as $cart_items) {

    $fetch_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shop_items` WHERE item_id = '$cart_items'"); 
    while($shop_items = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_info)) {
    $item_id = $shop_items['item_id'];
    $item_name = $shop_items['item_name'];
    $item_quantity = count(array_keys($session_quantity, $item_id));
    $item_price = $shop_items['item_price'] * $item_quantity; }

  $cartOutput .= '<h2>'.$item_name.'</h2>';
  $cartOutput .= '<a> Quantity: '.$item_quantity.'</a><br>';
  $cartOutput .= '<a> Price: '.number_format((float)$item_price, 2, '.', '').' USD</a><br>';
  $cartOutput .= '<a> ID: '.$item_id.'</a><br><br>';

  }
```

Comment: post your code so that we can help properly.

Comment: Is it an invisible `foreach()` function?

Comment: If by "variable called $item_price" you actually meant an array key and value, then [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column)+[`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum) might suffice.

Comment: @ApulGupta I just added the foreach()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use updated code:

```
    $total = 0;
    foreach($session_cart as $cart_items) {

        $fetch_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shop_items` WHERE item_id = '$cart_items'"); 
        // while($shop_items = mysql_fetch_array($fetch_info)) { //<- No need of loop here as only one will be returned everytime
        $shop_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_info); //<- use this instead
        $item_id = $shop_items['item_id'];
        $item_name = $shop_items['item_name'];
        $item_quantity = count(array_keys($session_quantity, $item_id));
        $item_price = $shop_items['item_price'] * $item_quantity; 
        //} //<- Closing while loop removed

      $cartOutput .= '<h2>'.$item_name.'</h2>';
      $cartOutput .= '<a> Quantity: '.$item_quantity.'</a><br>';
      $cartOutput .= '<a> Price: '.number_format((float)$item_price, 2, '.', '').' USD</a><br>';
      $cartOutput .= '<a> ID: '.$item_id.'</a><br><br>';

      $total+=$item_price; //<- Sums up for grand total
      }

      echo $total; //<- shows grand total
```

Comment: Thank you so much - It work exactly as i need it to! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$total  = 0;
foreach($array as $row)
{
  $total += $row['item_price'];
  //the rest of your code in foreach
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: I need it to be outside the foreach()